# what whould be suitable algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

I am trying to do c++ program.I am trying to do problem in which i have numbers of points. Now i need to find the path that goes through all the points. This is not actually TSP because as per my knowledge in TSP it is possible to travel from all points to every other points. But in my case the path network between the points is fixed and i just need to find the suitable path that goes through all the points provided that all points may not have connection to every other point..so what algorithm am i supposed to follow.

Comment: TSP is still relevant. Even if you can't revisit nodes, it's still (non-metric) TSP.

Comment: Also, `C++` is not a good tag for this question. Try `algorithm`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a way to traverse a graph? If so have you tried Breadth first search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search or Depth first search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search to traverse your graph.

Comment: Based on the asker's wording, this might be the case. +1

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) for a graph.

> In the mathematical field of graph theory, a Hamiltonian path (or
>   traceable path) is a path in an undirected graph that visits each
>   vertex exactly once. A Hamiltonian cycle (or Hamiltonian circuit) is a
>   Hamiltonian path that is a cycle. Determining whether such paths and
>   cycles exist in graphs is the Hamiltonian path problem, which is
>   NP-complete.

Some [techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) that exist :

> There are n! different sequences of vertices that might be Hamiltonian
>   paths in a given n-vertex graph (and are, in a complete graph), so a
>   brute force search algorithm that tests all possible sequences would
>   be very slow. There are several faster approaches. A search procedure
>   by Frank Rubin divides the edges of the graph into three classes:
>   those that must be in the path, those that cannot be in the path, and
>   undecided. As the search proceeds, a set of decision rules classifies
>   the undecided edges, and determines whether to halt or continue the
>   search. The algorithm divides the graph into components that can be
>   solved separately. Also, a dynamic programming algorithm of Bellman,
>   Held, and Karp can be used to solve the problem in time O(n2 2n). In
>   this method, one determines, for each set S of vertices and each
>   vertex v in S, whether there is a path that covers exactly the
>   vertices in S and ends at v. For each choice of S and v, a path exists
>   for (S,v) if and only if v has a neighbor w such that a path exists
>   for (S − v,w), which can be looked up from already-computed
>   information in the dynamic program.
>
> Andreas Björklund provided an alternative approach using the
>   inclusion–exclusion principle to reduce the problem of counting the
>   number of Hamiltonian cycles to a simpler counting problem, of
>   counting cycle covers, which can be solved by computing certain matrix
>   determinants. Using this method, he showed how to solve the
>   Hamiltonian cycle problem in arbitrary n-vertex graphs by a Monte
>   Carlo algorithm in time O(1.657n); for bipartite graphs this algorithm
>   can be further improved to time O(1.414n).
>
> For graphs of maximum degree three, a careful backtracking search can
>   find a Hamiltonian cycle (if one exists) in time O(1.251n).

Comment: Is it necessary that ever network consists of a hamiltonian path?